# Why I am getting the Network main thread exception for accessing a spreadsheet?

Tags: android, networking, spreadsheet

I'm getting many exceptions like NetworkMainthread. And yes I have followed the steps from https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String USERNAME = "xyz@gmail.com";
    String PASSWORD = "rrrrrrr";


    URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = null;
    try {
        SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");
        /*https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/public/full");*/
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1");
    service.setProtocolVersion(SpreadsheetService.Versions.V3);
    try {
        service.setUserCredentials(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    SpreadsheetFeed feed = null;
    try {
        feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL,SpreadsheetFeed.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();
    SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet = spreadsheets.get(0);
    System.out.println(spreadsheet.getTitle().getPlainText());
    WorksheetFeed worksheetFeed = null;
    try {
        worksheetFeed = service.getFeed(
                spreadsheet.getWorksheetFeedUrl(), WorksheetFeed.class);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ServiceException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
        List<WorksheetEntry> worksheets = worksheetFeed.getEntries();
        WorksheetEntry worksheet = worksheets.get(0);

        URL listFeedUrl = worksheet.getListFeedUrl();
        ListFeed listFeed = null;
        try {
            listFeed = service.getFeed(listFeedUrl, ListFeed.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       List<ListEntry> list = listFeed.getEntries();

        for (ListEntry row : list) {
            System.out.println(row.getTitle().getPlainText() + "\t" + row.getPlainTextContent());
        }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Take a look to this article - https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#AsyncTask.
Since Android 4.0 all network requests should be performed in separate thread or exception will occurs.

Answer (score 3):

NetWorkOnMaiNThread Exception occurs because you are attempting to make network related operation in the Main UI Thread. This is not possible.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

You can use asynctask if its for short duration.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

A quote from the above link

**AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.)**

You can display a progressdialog in onPreExecute(). Perform Network related operation in doInBackground(). But do not update ui from doinBackground() ( doInbackground() runs on the background thread). Return result in doInBAckground(). The result of doInBackground() is a parameter to onPostExecute(). In onPostExecute() dismiss dialog and update the ui accrodingly.

You can also create a thread and do the network related operation. If you create threads you need to be careful not to update ui from the thread. ui should be updated on the main ui thread.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html

Answer (score 0):

Android 3.0 onward doesn't support network call in main UI thread.
You can use Thread or AsyncTask to achieve the network call.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not recommended but helps..

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            }
```